# jquery image added to page but it is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, image

I have a div tag.

```
<div class="imsSummaryItem" id="imagesPreview">
</div>
<asp:Image ImageUrl="C:\Users\John\Desktop\TempFolder\16.jpg" runat="server" /> --not showing up as well.
```

In my javascript:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function loadImages() {
     $('#imagesPreview').append('<img src="C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\TempFolder\\16.jpg" />');
  }
</script>
```

I am ending up with a hollow image. I dont see it. Just like an icon but its empty.I hope you understand what I mean. When I check the image properties it says 16.jpg and remaining all values are Not Available. What is wrong here?

Comment: Why do you have so many backslashes?

Comment: check you path or use "./16.jpg" if your website files were at the TempFolder

Comment: try to add the same image directly after div and see if it is displaying

Comment: Unless you're in IE with certain privileges allowed, I don't think you can reference an image from your local hard drive like that.

Comment: @AhsanShah.I added that image immediately after my div and it didnt show up as well. See the edited question what I mean.

Comment: @jfriend00.For testing purpose I am doing this. What will I have to do when I put my code on a server machine? I am testing in IE.

Comment: @RUJordan.If i did not put those slashes it showed up as a string with no slashes and 16 became some weird 0E.jpg or something like that.

Comment: @RookieAppler: so something wrong with your image path... not because of appending using jQuery.

Comment: @AhsanShah. How could that be?Its on my desktop.I traversed to that folder.Inside that I have the image. I get the path from the windows explorer(C:\Users\John\Desktop\TempFolder) and to that i append "\16.jpg" and pasted it here. I chose some different folder on my desktop which had a .png image. Same problem

Comment: @RookieAppler: i explained the problem and solution in my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think image you are trying to show is not in web application folder / virtual directory.

Move image to your web application folder and then specify the relative or an absolute URL in `ImageUrl` property.

If you dont want to move images to your web folder then your only choice is to write `HttpHandler` which will read images from specified folder and transmit it to the client. This will also require some specific permissions for your web app IIS user to access some folder outside the web app scope.

Answer (score 0):

I think escape sequence is not correct that is why it not able to reach that path.

try this: double backslash before forward slash ... SO is not allowing me to write it properly, it is omitting one back slash. i hope you got my point

```
"C:\\\/Users\\\/John\\\/Desktop\\\/TempFolder\\\/16.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

Always try to have the images you need inside your solution.

Just copy the image from temp folder and have it inside the resources

Like have the image in Resources/Images folder so that you can refer it as

```
 $('#imagesPreview').append('<img src="../Resources/Images/16.jpg" alt="text" />
```